# jQuery prevent parent action on child onclick event

Tags: jquery

I am trying to prevent parent click action when click on child element

My JavaScript code:

```
$(".profile").bind("mouseenter mouseleave click",function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
//if blocks depending of one of three actions
}
```

And inside that .profile element is DIV with list

```
<div id="tooltip-content" class="tooltip center" style="display: block;">
        <ul>
            <li id="name">Toms IrForšs </li>
            <li id="main"><a onclick="something()">1</a></li>
            <li id="remove"><a onclick="something()">2</a></li>
            <li id="sendmail"><a onclick="something()">3</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

But when the something method is called the parent click event is also fired.

Comment: Where exactly is the `.profile` element?

Comment: You need to `stopPropagation()` inside of your `something()` function

Comment: Yeah, good question... Your code does not describe your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 $(".profile").bind("mouseenter mouseleave click",function(e){ 
   if (e.target == this)
   {
      //do your stuff
   }
 });
```

this will execute the code inside the if condition only when the element clicked is the same element that was bound.

and use `on()` instead of `bind()`

Answer (score 0):

I created the fiddle for you, with concept that should work for you ([link](http://jsfiddle.net/5phXG/)) with little changes in your code.

What you miss, is canceling propagation - using `stopImmediatePropagation` method.

That's it!